# why a const references can point to constant while normal reference can not

Tags: c++, reference

In c++, a reference variable can refer to an object as below

```
int i;

int &ref = i;
```

BUT if we put **"const"** keyword it can take any value, may be some variable or constant value.

Could some one brief me on this?

Regards,
Abhineet

Comment: @40two: pointers have the exact same issue

Comment: @MooingDuck you are right is a general rule.

Comment: @Luchian: THe OP is **not** talking about binding a temporary object to a non-const reference.

Comment: @Deduplicator I think OP **is** asking about that.

Comment: @Deduplicator i think he is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as `const`-correctness.

The standard does not define any implicit conversions from cv-qualified to less qualified types, and references act mostly like pointers which can only be assigned once and dereference automatically(Though you cannot bind a non-const lvalue to a non-const reference).

Still, you can use `const_cast` to override the compiler. On your own head be it then.